# Multi-network PCIe WiFi card do they exist?

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, pci-express

I'm looking for a PCIe WiFi card that will allow me to connect to 2 separate WiFi networks simultaneously.

I've tried searching but keywords like dual network, dual band, dual SSID etc etc but they mostly relate to 2.4 / 5G or MIMO rather that what I am looking for!

Does anyone know of a card that allows that or what that feature might be called to aid with the search?

I'd ideally like to avoid taking up 2 slots with cards and USB adapters are just a pain.

Comment: This is to do with the software, not the card. My little router allows me to create multiple SSIDs on a single interface. If you can find the right software, then the answer is yes.

Comment: @Bib what do you mean with "my little router"? the OP is asking to connect a PC, not a router

Comment: @1NN I am pointing out that it is possible and it is not a hardware limitation.

Comment: @Bib one thing is a ROUTER, which usually can transmit more than one WiFi signal to avoid network congestion. another thing is a PERIPHERAL which usually allows to connect only to one network. The OP specifically asks about a PCIe card, which is a completely different thing from a router!

Comment: @1NN matters not a jot. With the correct software/firmware you can. We can argue about this till the cows come home...

Comment: @Bib it totally matters. One AP, many networks: One channel. One client, many networks: not necessarily one channel. It absolutely is a hardware limitation.

Comment: @DanielB try telling that to my router, you can have multiple SSIDs on a single channel with a single interface. We are going around in circles and I am out of here...

Comment: … yes, that is exactly what I wrote? OP wants to connect a _client_ to multiple networks, which may or may not be on the same Wi-Fi channel. They are most likely not. Wi-Fi adapters (whether in a router or in a client) are limited to a single channel.

Answer (score 2):

No, a Wi-Fi adapter with two radios does not exist<sup>1</sup>. You need two radios to connect to two different channels.

If you know for certain that both networks you connect to will *always* be on the same channel, one radio is enough.

There are PCIe-to-M.2 adapter cards—even with multiple slots—but those are designed for SSDs. They do not offer the required antenna connectivity. It could also not work at all due to missing features on the M.2 slots, interference and whatnot.

And then there’s also the software issue mentioned in comments and other answers: With Linux this all is “easy”. On Windows, it probably isn’t. I was not able to find conclusive evidence that Windows supports multiple Wi-Fi adapters properly. So even if you use multiple USB adapters, you may be out of luck.

---

1: Even your “simultaneous dual-band Wi-Fi router” will have two complete Wi-Fi chipsets installed to provide both 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz networks at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I never heard of such a card, but anyway this is more a question
of the software that is driving the card, if it can emulate
two virtual network cards when using the one physical card.

By default Windows 10 will only use one WiFi connection,
choosing the one that is performing better.
Even if you have two WiFi cards, Windows will use only one.

The only way to use two connections concurrently is to merge the two
into one, or to use an application that will expressly specify the
network card to which it will connect.

The only solution I can think of is to use a virtual machine.
A virtual machine can have two virtual network adapters, and both
will go through your one physical network card.

Windows running in such a virtual machine will be able to use
two connections.